# How to pass an array through ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form for a referral system which has two fields namely Name and email. I also have a 'refer another friend' button which allows the user to refer another friend (capped off to 11). So another Name and email field appears. Now I have also an ajax function `$.post` which is designed to take only one Name and email.

How do I make the ajax function work properly if there are more than one email entries (which can be different for different users). One thing I can think of is using an array after function `addInput()` and then passing it to ajax. Can someone help me figure this thing out?

```
    <script>
var countBox =1;
var boxName = 0;
function addInput()
{
     if(countBox<20)
     {  
     var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<input name="name" size="50" class="resize" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Name" required type="text" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+'" "  />';
     countBox += 1;
     var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/><input name="email" size="50" class="resize" required placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Email Address" type="text" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+'" "  /><br/><br/>';
     countBox += 1;
     }
     else{
         alert("Max number of referrals reached");
         }
}
</script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#emailForm').validate({
            submitHandler: function() {
                $.post("index1.php",{"name":$('#name').val(),"email":$('#email').val(),"userid": "<?php echo($user) ?>"},function(data) {
                    
                    if(data == "Email address has already received a referral")
                        alert("Email address has already received a referral");
                    else {
                        count = 3 - parseInt(data)
                        var content = "You have "+count+" referrals left";
                        $('h4').html(content);
                        alert ("Referral sent");
                    }
                });
            }
            });
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to make json array on client side and pass it to as string on server like below one

```
   [{"name" : "A","email" : "a@gmail.com"},{"name" : "B","email" : "b@gmail.com"},{"name" : "C","email" : "c@gmail.com"}]
```

on serverside use

```
json_decode($json)
```

will give you

```
  array
  0 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'A' (length=1)
      'email' => string 'a@gmail.com' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'B' (length=1)
      'email' => string 'b@gmail.com' (length=11)
  2 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'C' (length=1)
      'email' => string 'c@gmail.com' (length=11)
```

reference

http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

I think you can append all the names to a single string with a separator in middle
like

```
name=name1+","+name2;
email=email1+","+email2;
```

and now you can send it through ajax.

and on other side you can split it into an array using `split()` function

I am not familiar with PHP so excuse me if i am wrong. But this logic actually works good for me in JSP

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
<input name="name[]">
```

and

```
<input name="email[]">
```

and it looks like you'll need to have

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo($user) ?>">
```

Then, you can use

```
 $.post("index1.php", $('#emailForm').serialize());
```

Then, in your php, you just need to loop through your post variables:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['email']); $i++) {
  $email = $_POST['email'][$i];
  $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
  doStuff($name, $email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using the jQuery `.serialize()` method (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Also, you might want to name your inputs like this:

`name="name[]"` and `name="email[]"`. Otherwise if you pass all the posted inputs you'll only pass the last one of each since their names will overwrite each other.